# How to convert UTC to PST in Excel for day and time formats?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel, I have a cell which is

```
13 05:58:57
```

which represents day 13, 5 am, 58 minutes, 57 seconds in UTC time.

I would like to convert to PST, which should be

```
12 10:58:57
```

which is day 12, 10 pm, 58 minutes, 57 seconds.

The day is just a day of the month. Is there a way to do this quickly in excel?

Comment: Try `=CONCATENATE("2022/01/",A1) - (7/24)`.

Comment: BTW, would change to PDST also need to be considered?